# How to create list of unique array items from thousands of records in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I have an `Artist` model with a `genres` jsonb column that has data like this:

```
> Artist.first.genres
=>["alternative emo", "anthem emo", "dreamo", "emo", "neon pop punk", "pop emo", "pop punk"]

> Artist.last.genres
=> ["emo", "brooklyn indie", "indie pop", "indie poptimism", "indie rock", "indietronica", "modern rock", "shimmer pop"]
```

What I'd like to do is scan all of the artist records and generate a single list of all the unique genres across every artist.

This would be done across 10-20k artists, with each having any combo of one to dozens of genres.

Ultimately just looking for an array as the output.

In the event it's useful, I'm running Rails 5.2.3 and Ruby 2.6.1.

Comment: Would "brooklyn indie" be considered *"unique"* in comparison to "indie rock" or should the genres be separated as `["brooklyn","indie", "indie", "rock"]`?

Comment: @engineersmnky "brooklyn indie" would be unique in comparison to "indie rock".

Answer (score 2):

So you are going to have to unfold that column into values (as a subquery) then select the distinct values from there. 
I am not all the familiar with this but possibly something like

```
Artist.distinct
  .from("SELECT jsonb_array_elements_text(genres) AS genre FROM artists")
  .pluck(:genre)
```

This should result in an `Array` from the following query

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  genre
FROM 
  (SELECT jsonb_array_elements_text(genres) AS genre FROM artists) subquery
```

Which according to my understanding of the [PostgreSQL Docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-json.html) should work.